# Can I use the auto value with the calc() property?

Tags: css, css-calc

I wanted to set `margin` to `auto` plus some pixel amount using `calc()`, but my code doesn't seem to work.

```css
selector {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
    margin: calc(auto + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Can I set `calc()` to an automatic margin plus a fixed value? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried by defining percentage but it will not go as my div is smaller or larger may.

Comment: hope keeping margin @ auto and translateX -5px will do the trick I believe.

Comment: @vssadineni The question is basically related to some percentage calculation. So used both in my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at my own question today, I feel ashamed why I couldn't think it correctly? Basically, auto margin is what left margin 50% minus width of the div. In this basis, we can layout the element like this:

```
margin-left: calc(50% + 5px);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Using the preceding code is equivalent to `calc(auto + 5px);`. Since, calc doesn't support auto we need to trick with actual concept of translation. This means we can also layout with absolute position with the concept of `50% - half of width`, but I like `transform` here for simplicity.

See the demo below:

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.right{
  margin-left: calc(50% + 20px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.left{
  margin-left: calc(50% - 20px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#border{
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="auto" class="child">
    auto margin
  </div>
  <div id="auto-right" class="child right">
    auto + pushed to right
  </div>
  <div class="child left">
    auto + pushed to left
  </div>
  <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

Increase or decrease the plus minus value of left and right to understand it correctly.

**Note:** using the below code

```
.right{
  margin-left: calc(50% + 20px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

is same as using:

```
.right{
  margin-right: calc(50% - 20px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

for this concept.

**Also note** that the question is related to some percentage calculation plus minus desired shift. So in this answer, it has both calc and transform is used. If you exactly require to shift at middle then we could just use (without margin-left or margin-right):

```
transform: translateX(-20px)
```

The answer is provided with 50% calc but the question was requiring to use some percentage like `calc(20% - 20px)`.

Answer (score 17):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) :

> The calc() CSS function can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`,
>   `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is required. With calc(), you
>   can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

You *cannot use* `auto` there, as it's not a valid value for `calc()`.

Grammar for `calc()`

```
term
  : unary_operator?
    [ NUMBER S* | PERCENTAGE S* | LENGTH S* | EMS S* | EXS S* | ANGLE S* |
      TIME S* | FREQ S* ]
  | STRING S* | IDENT S* | URI S* | hexcolor | function | math
  ;
```

For more information, refer the [Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation)

---

As you commented that you want to center the `div` but you also want a `5px` `margin` on the `right` than you can achieve it by using `text-align: center;` on the parent element and make the child `div` elements to `display: inline-block;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/2jgr6/)

Output

[image]

```
div.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}

div.wrap div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
}

div.wrap div.with_margin {

    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #f00;
}

div.wrap div.without_margin { 
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: oh! there is function too. how can I use to make likely to auto + 5px?

Comment: @C-link It doesn't make any sense, how it will be auto, when you are adding `5px` `margin` on the right? Can you show a representational way, of what you expect?

Comment: try to understand comparing these demos: http://jsfiddle.net/jP7mN/1/   http://jsfiddle.net/jP7mN/2/  . It will be set the margin-right 25% whatever the div width is but I wanted to behave like both side auto but plus some width margin from right side.

Answer (score -1):

I just stumbled on this from a search. It seems a bit complicated though. Why not separating and have a div with margin auto and the element inside with a margin left? Like so:

HTML:

```
 <div class="centered">
   <div>Some sort of element here</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
  margin: auto;
 }
.centered:first-child {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: -2%;
 }
```

Comment: OP's own answer from four years ago uses this method already.