# How to give margin-left in proportion to margin-right?

Tags: css

Here in my screen, I have given the margin-left and margin-right equal right now. But I need is, margin-right should be 'x' and margin-left should be 'x/1.5'. While the margin-right is auto as per the window size.

Comment: Share your code and what you have tried so far. So that others can help you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :) Can you provide a minimal example of what you are trying as fiddle or codepen link, that will help the community in answering

Comment: You might be able to do something with relative positioning. Otherwise, JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function calc() to do that.

```
.myDiv {
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-left: calc(1em / 1.5);
}
```

Check this if you want more info about that function. It's pretty interesting tho https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @amit `calc()` function does not support `auto`. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275565/using-calc-with-auto-margin

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to center the element then to offset it slightly from the center by having the `auto` configuration but without equal values.

Here is an idea where you can rely on flexbox to achieve this behavior:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin:20px;
}

.box {
  width:80px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  margin:auto;
}
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.flex:before,
.flex:after{
  content:"";
}
.flex:after {
  flex-grow:1.5; /*will grow more than the before by 1.5 */ 
}
.flex:before {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper flex">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define width with for right in numbers, that can be find with js/jquery then use this:

Just updated code, please check now

[`Margin Issue`](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/wbKwjm)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css custom-properties and media-queries:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lime;
}
.box-with-margin {
  --margin-value: 2rem;
  margin-left: var(--margin-value);
  margin-right: calc(3 * var(--margin-value));
}

@media (max-width: 1600px) {
  .box-with-margin {
    --margin-value: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .box-with-margin {
    --margin-value: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box-with-margin"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```